# UITesting with Multiple XCTestCase Class

Tags: cocoa, compiler-errors, xcode-ui-testing, duplicate-symbol, modularization

I am writing UITest cases for my Project. So I want to have multiple files either subclassed to XCTestCase or subclassed to my Other Test Classes. Whenever I create a such File, I am getting the following error.

```
duplicate symbol _lastUsedSaveDirectory in:
/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug/Project_UITests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SecondaryFile.o
/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Intermediates/Project.build/Debug/Project_UITests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MainFile.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the following but nothing works:

```
1. Created "SecondaryFile" by subclassing it from "MainFile" which is a subclass of "XCTestCase".
2. Created "SecondaryFile" by subclassing it directly from "XCTestCase".
3. Created both .h and .m file for both the "MainFile" and "SecondaryFile"
```

MainFile.m

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface MainFile_UITests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation MainFile_UITests

- (void)setUp {
        [super setUp];

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];
        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
}

- (void)tearDown {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.    
}

@end
```

SecondaryFile.m

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>

@interface SecondaryFile_UITests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation SecondaryFile_UITests

- (void)setUp {
        [super setUp];

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        [[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];
        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
}

- (void)tearDown {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        [super tearDown];
}

@end
```

Could someone tell me how to modularise/Create multiple File UITesting classes.

Comment: Please post code of at least one of the files from the error

Comment: I have added a Sample code for both the Files. Please comment.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and deleting your derived data?

Comment: Yeah. I have even tried that but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use several UI Test files, you should first create a header file for `UITests.m`, then in your separate test files, inherit from `UITest.h`.  This will give you the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods from `UITests.m` in your subclasses. All you have to do then is add your new test methods to you subclasses.

As an example, here is an example of a subclassed UITests file in Objective-C: 
https://gist.github.com/OffensivelyBad/012043f8dab50b3b024238e985462926